# Список списков в языке python

Tags: python, список

Как создать список из списков из каждого элемента начального списка в python?

Comment: вы не публикуете что вы пробовали делать - это не хорошо. Покажите список, который является входным и что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Сможете показать родительский список?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
l_a=[[x] for x in a]
print(a,l_a)
```

Результат

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```