# Как каждый элемент списка преобразовать в новый список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список

```
['apple', 'melon','bread', 'Coffee']
```

Как из него сделать это?

```
[[apple], [melon], [bread], [Coffee]]
```

Comment: Что вы попробовали сделать самостоятельно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Список списков в языке python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078339/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-python)

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простое решение:

```
a = ['apple', 'melon', 'bread', 'Coffee']
b = [[x] for x in a]
print(b) # [['apple'], ['melon'], ['bread'], ['Coffee']]
```